# Rank of matrix as a function of x

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Given $B$=$\begin{pmatrix}
x & 1 & 2 \\ 
5 & 5 & -2 \\ 
3 & 3 & 6 \\ 
1 & x & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

Find rank of matrix $B$ as a function of $x$

For finding the rank I converted the above matrix to row reduced echelon form and got the following

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & \frac{-2}{5}\frac{x+1}{x-1}\\ 0 & 1 & \frac{12}{5}\frac{1}{x-1}\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 &0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

When $x \neq 1$ the rank of the above matrix is 3 and when $x=1$ rank of the above matrix is 2 but when $x=1$, I am getting infinite value in the last column.

Can you please let me know if the above approach to the formulation is correct?

Comment: Dividing by $x - 1$ is an incorrect step. Before applying this step, separate the problem into two cases: one where $x = 1$, and the other where $x \neq 1$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks had a query how to separate it in case of reduced row echelon form above?

Comment: You have to separate it *before* dividing by $(x - 1)$. If you could show the matrix that you have before doing so, then I could explain what to do from there.

Comment: @BenGrossmann got it now the matrix before is $ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & x & 2\\ 
0 & x-1 & 12/5\\ 
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $

Comment: Perfect. So for the case of $x = 1$, you now have the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 2\\ 0 & 0 & 12/5\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\0&0&0}.
$$
Here, we only have two pivot columns, so the rank will be $2$. For the case that $x \neq 1$, your original answer is correct, so we have a rank of $3$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $x=1$ there are two identical columns, independent to the third column, so rank =2.

As you've seen, when $x \ne 1$, the rank is three.

Comment: got it Thank you.

Comment: Sure! ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

If $x=1$ the two first columns are equal and independent from the last column. Hence the rank is equal to $2$

Comment: got it thank you